# filter date where dates are of last quarter

Tags: postgresql

From the table below, I would like to count how many times each customer had appointments in the last quarter.

dwh_schema.appointments

```
customer_id appointment id   created_at
A            1           2021-04-11 11:15:08
A            2           2021-06-11 11:15:08
A            3           2021-08-11 11:15:08
```

Current query

```
select customer_id, count(distinct appointment_id) as last_quarter_appointments
from dwh_schema.appointments 
where created_at::date >='2021-04-01' and created_at::date<='2021-06-30'
```

The problem with the query above is if I run it again next year, the data will be irrelevant,
as the last quarter is not dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group the data by year and quarter.
By using `extract` method, you can get the year and quarter of the date.

```sql
select customer_id, extract(year from created_at::date) as year, extract(quarter from created_at::date) as quarter, count(distinct appointment_id) as last_quarter_appointments from dwh_schema.appointments
group by extract(year from created_at::date), extract(quarter from created_at::date), customer_id
having extract(year from created_at::date) = extract(year from now()) and extract(quarter from created_at::date) = extract(quarter from now()) - 1;
```

And then do filter by `having` clause.

Comment: but with the query above, I have to change the query every quarter?

Comment: What do u mean? it shows data for all quarters.
Have you ever tried the query?

Comment: with the query above, next quarter, I need to change the having clause from extract(quarter from created_at) = 2 to 3?

Comment: So u want the current quarter right?
Just use extract method to now()
I have already done everything for you. 
Please have a little try.

Comment: sorry, you don't seem to understand my question. Currently, it's quarter 3. I only want datapoints which are (current_quarter - 1). But, we don't seem to have this current_quarter functionality in postgres (afaik). With your method, every quarter, I need to change the number. So, for instance, in quarter 4, I need to change extract(quarter from created_at) = 3. In quarter 1, 2022. I need to change the values again to extract(year from created_at::date) = 2021 and extract(quarter from created_at)=4. It's not dynamic.

Comment: the query will be used to produce a dashboard. It's not nice to change the query to create a dashboard every quarter.

Comment: Ok, just add this. “having extract(year from created_at::date) = extract(year from now()) and extract(quarter from created_at::date) = extract(quarter from now()) - 1”

Comment: works well. could you update your answer so I can approve it, please?

Comment: OK. updated. Please approve